# What is the point of limiting bounties to a maximum of 500 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I have looked at the [Help Center article about bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) and do not understand why there is a maximum on the amount of reputation you can offer as a bounty.

Note: this is not a duplicate of [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77196/how-come-i-cant-give-more-than-500-rep), because this question is asking what the reasoning behind it was, while that question is asking if it is a bug or not.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194624/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264481/282094

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77262) to the linked dupe directly answers the "why" question, and echoes what was answered below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it shouldn't be too easy to transfer a lot of reputation from one account to another; that would make fraud harder to detect, and potentially also bestow certain privileges on users who aren't ready for it. 500 point bounties are already quite rare and attract enough visibility for a question; it's not likely that a 1000 point bounty would attract much more views.

Comment: Indeed - as the more advanced voting rings most likely uses the bounty system as a way to secure reputation points from account destruction (reputation points laundering).